# Inverse of \$e^{as}F(s)\$; t-axis translation rule

Tags: circuit-analysis, laplace-transform

t-axis translation rule is easy to prove using the definition of laplace transform; the rule is:
$$\mathcal{L\{u(t-a)f(t-a)\} = e^{-as}F(s)} $$
I know this works only when we shift the function to the *right*(when \$a\$ is positive).
As an example, the inverse of \$\frac{e^{-3s}}{s^2+1}\$ is \$u(t-3)\sin(t-3)\$.

So how to find inverse of \$\frac{e^{+3s}}{s^2+1}\$ ?

---

Alternatively is there a way to express the laplace transform of \$u(t)f(t+a)\$ in terms of \$F(s)\$ ?

I feel there exists a formula because  \$u(t)f(t+a)\$ is a "subset" of the original function \$u(t)f(t)\$,
so its laplace transform must depend on \$F(s)\$

Answer (score 1):

Since any change before t=0 doesn't make sense, having \$u(t+a)\$ also doesn't make sense since it would mean that there was nothing happening before the time has started, and also that the step happens before t=0. [Wolfram alpha agrees](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inverse+laplace+exp%283s%29%2F%28s%5E2%2B1%29). OTOH, sympy returns `DiracDelta(t+3)` which, again, doesn't make sense. \$\sin(t+3)\$ is not really affected since it's the phase, so this term could exist.

But you can think of this problem in a different way: the magnitudes of both transfer functions are exactly the same, except their phases will be in oposition. This means that the second t.f. will have a positive phase, which means the system is not convergent. If you're not convinced, try building such a system (not a mathematical formula).